# Calculate Percentage of a Value in a Row With Decimals Rounded to 2 Places

Tags: sql, select, casting, decimal, rounding

I have a query that gives me the percentage of NULL values in a column:

```
SELECT
  Count(*)
FROM
  XYZ_Referrals
WHERE
  referral_source IS NULL
) * 100.0 / (
  Select
    Count(*)
  From
    XYZ_Referrals
) as 'referral source fields that are populated'
```

However, I need to round and truncate the value to only 2 decimal places. The following query rounds, but does not truncate:

```
SELECT
  Round
    (
        (
            (
                SELECT
                    Count(*)
                FROM
                    XYZ_Referrals
                WHERE
                    referral_source IS NULL
            )
        * 100.0 / Count(*)
        ),2,2
    )
    as 'referral source fields that are populated'
FROM
  XYZ_Referrals
```

The value returned is 5.600000000000

I've attempted CAST, with no success.

```
SELECT
    (
        Cast
            (
                Round
                    (
                        (
                            (
                                SELECT
                                    Count(*)
                                FROM
                                    XYZ_Referrals
                                WHERE
                                    referral_source IS NULL
                            )
                            * 100.0 / Count(*)
                        )
                    ),2
                AS DECIMAL(3,2)
            )
    )
    as 'referral source fields that are populated'
FROM
  XYZ_Referrals
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You were along the correct lines but had the precision in the `DECIMAL` incorrect:

```
SELECT CAST(5.600000000000 AS DECIMAL(10, 2))
```

This will cast the number to 10-digit precision with 2 decimal places.